# Projection onto a linear transformation of the non-negative orthant

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, projection

Given a vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a symmetric positive-definite matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

**The question:** How to find the projection of the vector $b$ onto the convex set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax \ge 0 \}$ ? (the inequality means that each component of LHS is non-negative)

I suspect that the solution might use the function $\max(\; \cdot \; , 0)$ and/or the spectral decomposition of $A$. However, I have not solved the problem yet.

Comment: I don't think there is a general easy closed form known for $A$. You might be lucky in some cases as when $A$ is the identify matrix (and you just take the pointwise maximum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has no closed-form solution because it is equivalent to [non-negative least square problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares).

Let $y=Ax$, your problem is equivalent to:
$$\arg\min_{y\geq0}\|A^{-1}y-b\|^2$$
which is the standard form of NNLS, a problem which is known that it has no closed-form solution.